# Create a row that sums the rows that do not have a data in all the columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Create a row that sums the rows that do not have a data in all the columns.

I'm working on a project that keeps throwing dataframes like this:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 108.864 |  | INTERCAMBIADORES DE | 1123.60 210.08 166.71 1333.68 |
|  |  |  | CALOR 8419500300 |  |
|  | 147.420 5.000 | PZ | 1A0181810000 | 81039.25 15149.52 19237.754880 96188.77 |
|  | 147.420 |  | INTERCAMBIADORES DE | 3882.25 725.75 921.60 4608.00 |
|  |  |  | CALOR 8419500300 |  |
|  | 566.093 12.000 | PZ | 1A0183660000 | 66187.40 12374.29 6546.806709 78561.68 |
|  | 566.093 |  | INTERCAMBIADORES DE | 3170.76 592.80 313.63 3763.56 |
|  |  |  | CALOR 8419500300 |  |
|  | 3.645 1.000 | PZ | 1A0185890000 | 836.64 159.69 996.330339 996.33 |
|  | 3.645 |  | INTERCAMBIADORES DE | 40.08 7.65 47.73 47.73 |
|  |  |  | CALOR 8419500300 |  |
|  | 131.998 3.000 | PZ | 1A0190390000 | 32819.41 6135.17 12984.858315 38954.57 |
|  | 131.998 |  | INTERCAMBIADORES DE | 1572.24 293.91 622.05 1866.15 |
|  |  |  | CALOR 8419500300 |  |
|  | 123.833 3.000 | PZ | 1A0190790000 | 54769.36 10238.84 21669.402087 65008.21 |
|  | 123.833 |  | INTERCAMBIADORES DE | 2623.77 490.50 1038.09 3114.27 |
|  |  |  | CALOR 8419500300 |  |
|  | 115.214 2.000 | PZ | 1A0195920000 | 54642.66 10215.05 32428.851279 64857.70 |
|  | 115.214 |  | INTERCAMBIADORES DE | 2617.70 489.36 1553.53 3107.06 |

This is going to insert a sql database, I don't know how to add the empty rows with the row that has all the information.
**NOTE:** Spacing Empty cells is variable

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Question is unclear: please provide code you've tried, the error message you're getting, and expected output.